# How can I escape a period/decimal inside URL Visual Studio Basic .NET VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, escaping

I am using an Amazon image URL that is this: **[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61pztRZYCKL.*SL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61pztRZYCKL._SL1500_.jpg)**

Notice the added period *inside* the file name...

How can I escape/encode that so that I can use this image URL in another API?

I'm using Visual Basic and do not want to save the file, rename, and upload...

What do I do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UrlEncode` method.  A number of classes have such a method and which one you should use depends on the type of application.